# How to iterate through multiple object keys in 1 for() loop

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop

```
x = {a:1,b:2}
y = {c:3,d:4}

for (k in x+y) {
  console.log(k)
}
```

Desired output:

```
a
b
c
d
```

I'm more used to Python in which case this would be easier but Javascript doesn't seem to let me do this. I want to do this in the **simplest way possible** because simplicity is bliss. If I can't do it simply, I'm afraid I might need to just combine x and y into 1 Object and add a 'type' key to each of their keys so I can filter by them, but I thought having pre-filtered keys as their own top-level Objects was more readable.

Comment: merge the objects first? [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Merging_objects)

Comment: Is there a simple way to do that? In Python I can merge 2 lists by just doing x+y but JavaScript doesn't seem to do this.

Comment: Sadly syntax doesn't carry from one programming language to another that way, you can still carry the logic though and do it the way that java-script understands it.

Comment: Try `Object.keys(Object.assign(x, y)).forEach(e => {console.log(e)});`

Comment: There are many alternatives, of which the most basic might be `Object.keys(x).concat(Object.keys(y))`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use two loops and move the code to a function in order to avoid repetition.

```
function iteration(key) {
  // ...
}
for (var key in x) iteration(key);
for (var key in y) iteration(key);
```

Or merge the two objects into a new one

```
for (var key in Object.assign({}, x, y) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: You properly want to send the object or the value to the function `iteration`

Comment: Merging will unfortunately result in a single key when a particular key was present in both objects.

Answer (score 0):

So i just figured an interesting workaround for this that is similar to the `Object.assign` way but without creating a new object for it.

Effectively you can do a `for/in` loop of both objects at once and order them in the same fashion as `Object.assign()` requires to get the same result.

taking your example:

```
var x = {a:1,b:2};
var y = {c:3,d:4};

// only since you want them in alphabetical order,
// same as I do obviously, you can do the following:

for(var key in x, y) {
  x[key] = y[key];
}
```

which gives you the output of this:

```
x = {
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  "c": 3,
  "d": 4
}
```